# How to set environment specific data for testing (detox framework + react-native app)

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, ui-automation, detox

I am new to the react-native world and sorry if a stupid question. I am writing e2e tests for a react-native app using the detox framework.

I have some data based on environment (test / staging / prod). Since, the app configuration is being set using the .env files, I tried to add a key value pair in the .env file and read them in my detox tests!

When I try to do an import of the react-native-config into my detox tests, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My question is how should I get environment specific data into tests? For eg. user account and password! If not .env file, what options do I have to set the environment specific data?

Thank you,
Kartik

I tried setting the values in the .env file, but seems we cannot use import in the tests!